# scapy: Timestamps lacking float precision on sniffed packets

Tags: windows, python-2.7, timestamp, scapy

While capturing packets on Windows 7 x64, timestamps don't seem to have float precision. the code is given below.

```
from scapy.all import sniff
pkts = sniff(count=10)
pkts[0].time
-> for higher precision output
print('%.6f'%pkts[0].time)
```

**output**

```
1506009934
1506009934.000000
```

any ideas how to get precise values for timestamps?

Comment: If you `print(type(pkts[0].time))` what do you get?

Comment: you are right on point it is giving me <type 'int'> in response. But how to correct that?

Comment: I don't know `scapy` and I can't find the `time` attribute in the documentation, so I don't know what units it's using. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @KashifAhmad Are you sure it didn't work. I tried your code (I use scapy 2.3.2) and printing just the timestamp I got `1506018140.84` and using `print('%.6f'%pkts[0].time)` I got `1506018140.836040` for the same timestamp.

Comment: Yes I am hundred percent sure about this. As I have some pcap files where I have assigned timestamps to packets. If you want to read those timestamps then it would give you float values. But when scapy tries to sniff or even with 'sr' function it wouldn't show any float values

Comment: plus: my version of scapy is 2.3.3.

Comment: @KashifAhmad I can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: This is really strange. I just shifted to windows 10 x64 and I am having the same issue again. May be I am missing something but the code is as simple as I have already posted.

Comment: @KashifAhmad I tried your code on _mac os_ and on a _linux virtual machine_ (_backbox with a bit older scapy version_) and faced no issue. Since I tried on linux using vm I can't say for sure that it is not an os related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in Scapy's development version. Get it from the [official repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/) and your code should give the results you expect.

Comment: I have tried the fixed version. Unfortunately its leading to many other problems. such as the output is not readable while pyreadline is already installed. Therefore coming back to the version 2.3.3 without latest update. Updated version throws an error upon start.`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Logged from file error.py, line 76`

Comment: Then you have an issue, which is totally unrelated with your question, and can probably be fixed. Open an issue on the project's GitHub! (and post the full stack trace).